# How can I change application variable outside Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

Hi I am trying to alter the variable of Application variable outside Global.asax but the previous data seems to appear again. Is there any way I can change the variable's value or reset  it. thanks ...

```
In Global.asax :

 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Application["abc"] = "";
 }

In  aspx.cs page :

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      ViewState["countmsg"] = 0;
   }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ViewState["countmsg"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["countmsg"]) +1;
   Application["abc"] = Application["abc"] + "hello" + Environment.NewLine;
   string str = Application["abc"].ToString();
     if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["countmsg"]) >= 4)
     {
        Application["abc"] = "";    // here the reset is not working
        ViewState["countmsg"] = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code. What variable? Where?

Comment: Worker processes/AppDomains can be restarted; and a different process can be used for subsequent requests. Not even "static" variable values are safe from "being forgotten" if not set each request (as what is generally done in "global.asax"). As such, "static" variables are generally not a good way to persist/store data. But, thankfully, there are likely *alternative approaches* depending on use-case - show current code!

Comment: @pst Sir can you help me selecting the appropriate approach in my case

Comment: global.asax is first file which gets loaded so everytime you request your site, every modification done in page gets overwritten.

Comment: Hmmm thanks a lot to all of you after some R&D i got the answer actually in button's click event I had to use reset code between       Application.Lock();                                                   --- my reset code ---- ;                                   Application.UnLock();

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ViewState["countmsg"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["countmsg"]) +1;
  Application["abc"] = Application["abc"] + "hello" + Environment.NewLine;
  string str = Application["abc"].ToString();

   if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["countmsg"]) >= 4)
   {
    Application.Lock();
    Application["abc"] = "";    // now its working
    Application.UnLock();  
    ViewState["countmsg"] = 0;
  }
}
```